# Package parskip to add more (or remove) vertical space

Tags: spacing, parskip

If you want vertical space between your paragraphs and no indentation, then as I have seen, the best solution is to use the parskip package. But in the documentation that package has no options, so how do you change that vertical space if you want to add more or less of it?

Comment: Not sure what the package offers, but you can do it package free, with `\parindent=0pt\relax` and `\parskip=<your dimension>\relax` in your preamble (or anywhere where you want it to change), where `<your dimension>` is the desired amount of `\parskip`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes But that's not recommended as `parskip` makes adjustments to mitigate the inevitable side-effects. (Not complete adjustments, but much better than nothing.)

Comment: @cfr side effects?  this is news to me.  Do you have a pointer?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was thinking exactly the same as cfr. Actually I have read some answers by you concerning `\parindent`. :)

Comment: @Adam If you are hoping to use one of my own answers against me, that's not allowed ! `:^)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Haha no not against you I just said that in order to show you that I understood the solution you mentioned.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `texdoc parskip`. I assume you are sufficiently conversant with LaTeX to read off the side-effects from the precautions the package takes ;).

Comment: @cfr I just pulled up the `parskip.pdf` 2-page doc.  I guess your valid point is that a properly formulated `\parskip` should have some glue in it, which is turned off with a simple specification such as `\parskip=1ex\relax`.  Good point.  Also, it affects list-making vertical spaces.

Comment: Well, since it is so short a package, one could copy it to `myparspace.sty`, change to `\ProvidesPackage{myparskip}` and change this line `\parskip=0.5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt` to the desired value.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is a really solid idea. What I wonder is when someone is writing a book and wants to control that vertical space what does he use? It seems weird that there is not a readily available solution.

Comment: I agree.  It would seem that making it a package option would be useful.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes And since so many things are lists, list spacing has rather wide ranging effects i.e. not just on the things which 'look like' lists but all the other 'trivial' lists ....

Comment: @Adam Perhaps one of the classes which handles this kind of customisation by design? As `parskip`'s manual makes clear, that is at best a 'quick fix'. To do it properly, you need a class designed to accommodate it from the ground up.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes If you want you can add your solution as an answer. If in the next day no one offers a better one I will accept it.

Comment: @cfr I guess you are right about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I take `parskip.sty`, rename it as `myparskip.sty` and make the following changes:

1) change to `\ProvidesPackage{myparskip}`

2) change

```
\parskip=0.5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
```

to

```
\ifdim\parskip>0pt\relax
  \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
\else
  \parskip=0.5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
\fi
```

This has the effect if called with a zero value of `\parskip`, it mimics what the `parskip` package would do (which is to set `\parskip` to a value of `0.5\baselineskip`).  On the other hand, if `\parskip` is specified to a non-zero value in advance of calling the package, it will take that as the new default value and do the other things the `parskip` package would do, such as adding glue to the `\parskip` dimension, and adjusting vertical dimensions associated with list making.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myparskip}

\ifdim\parskip>0pt\relax
  \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
\else
  \parskip=0.5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
\fi
\parindent=\z@

%
% from a suggestion by Donald Arseneau on comp.text.tex:

\DeclareOption{parfill}{\setlength{\parfillskip}{30\p@ \@plus 1fil}}
\ProcessOptions

% To accompany this, the vertical spacing in the list environments is changed
% to use the same as \parskip in all relevant places (for normalsize only):
%   \parsep = \parskip
%   \itemsep = \z@ % add nothing to \parskip between items
%   \topsep = \z@ % add nothing to \parskip before first item

\def\@listI{\leftmargin\leftmargini
   \topsep\z@ \parsep\parskip \itemsep\z@}
\let\@listi\@listI
\@listi

\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
   \labelwidth\leftmarginii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
   \topsep\z@ \parsep\parskip \itemsep\z@}

\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
    \labelwidth\leftmarginiii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
    \topsep\z@ \parsep\parskip \itemsep\z@}

% and, now...
%   \partopsep = \z@ % don't even add anything before first item (beyond 
%                    % \parskip) even if the list is preceded by a blank line
\partopsep=\z@

% Note that listiv, listv and listvi don't change vertical parameters.

% deal with a problem raised on comp.text.tex in april 2001
%
% don't expand the table of contents any further
%
% first: check that the definition of \@starttoc is unchanged from
% that in latex.ltx
\@ifundefined{CheckCommand}{}{%
  \CheckCommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \makeatletter
      \@input{\jobname.#1}%
      \if@filesw
        \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
        \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
      \fi
      \@nobreakfalse
    \endgroup}}
%
% now having generated any warning that might help, redefine
\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \parskip\z@
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}

\endinput
```

Consider this MWE, which gives the default `parskip` package behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\parskip\baselineskip
\usepackage{myparskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item the first
\item the second
\item the third
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

When the `\parskip` value is set in advance (uncomment the one line in the preamble), it affects the paragraph and list-making spacing both:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt}
```

which will override the default value `0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt`.

---

If you want a packaged version, save the following as `oparskip.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{oparskip}[2016/05/02]

\DeclareOption{parfill}{\PassOptionsToPackage{parfill}{parskip}}
\DeclareOption*{\edef\oparskip@factor{\CurrentOption}}

\ExecuteOptions{0.5} % default

\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parskip}{\oparskip@factor\baselineskip plus 2pt}

\endinput
```

Then you can call

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[0.75]{oparskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item the first
\item the second
\item the third
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```

If you want the equivalent of `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` with a modified factor, call

```
\usepackage[0.75,parfill]{oparskip}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the [revised parskip package](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/parskip/parskip.pdf) wants the skip value specified in the option, like so:

```
\usepackage[skip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt]{parskip}
```

As Frank says in the documentation, it isn't perfect.  I notice squishing when the page has elements that aren't in the main body of the test, such as tables, equations, and footnotes.